# EXIF rotation works fine with iOS, but not Android?

Tags: php, android, image-processing, image-uploading, exif

I'm developing an PHP web-app with the ability to upload pictures.
In the controller, I set the rotation like this:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($config['source_image']);

        if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation']))
        {
            $ort = $exif['Orientation'];

            if ($ort == 6 || $ort == 5)
                $config['rotation_angle'] = '270';
            if ($ort == 3 || $ort == 4)
                $config['rotation_angle'] = '180';
            if ($ort == 8 || $ort == 7)
                $config['rotation_angle'] = '90';
            if ($ort == 1 || $ort == 2)
                $config['rotation_angle'] = '0';


        }

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 

        if ( ! $this->image_lib->rotate())
        {

            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
```

This works fine when images are uploaded from an iOS device, but has no effect with Android.
Thank you for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: Is there an error message from the line `echo $this->image_lib->display_errors()` (where you previously had the comment "Error messages here")? If so, can you add it to your post?

Comment: Hi @JonathanLam ! No, there is no error message. It just uploads the image without rotating it

Comment: I think there is no exif information in android images your have uploaded. Check this

Comment: What is the effect you are after? And why is it that you mess around with exif rotation?